# Unable to apply CSS in Angular using ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am stuck at it for a long long time now and I really need help. I have a div section which I want to display on the click of a button. For which I use CSS classes.

Here is the DIV section

```
    <div class="elen-main--left-menu--collapsed " ng-class="collapsedMenuAvailable">
    <div class="icon-propal icon_active">
        <img src="content/img/icon_propal_white.svg" alt="" width="18" />
    </div>

    <div class="icon-contrat">
        <img src="content/img/icon_contrat_grey.svg" alt="" width="18" />
    </div>
    <div class="left--menu--expand" ng-click="vm.showVerticalBanner">
        <img src="content/img/arrow-expandMenu-grey.svg" alt="" width="13">
    </div>
</div>
```

collapsedMenuAvailable is changed to the value from my controller. 
CONTROLLER

```
vm.hideVerticalBanner = function () {
                $scope.collapsedMenuAvailable = 'expandCollapsedMenu';
                $('.elen-main--left-menu').addClass('collapseLeftMenu');
                $('.elen-main--left-menu').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // $('.elen-main--left-menu--collapsed').addClass('expandCollapsedMenu');
                    $('.elen-main--content').css('width', 'calc(100% - 6rem)');
                }, 200);

                $('.elen-main--left-menu').removeClass('expandLeftMenu');
                $('.elen-main--left-menu--collapsed').removeClass('collapseCollapsedMenu');
            }
```

But still it doesn't apply the CSS. However if I put the classname which is 'expandCollapsedMenu' in the div section, the CSS is applied.

what is possibly wrong ?

Comment: what style is associated with `.expandCollapsedMenu`?

Comment: You are missing parentheses ~ `ng-click="vm.someFunction()"`

Comment: very likely its just the parenthesis

Comment: Which parentheses ? I did vm.showVerticalBanner() as well and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JaromandaX: The stype associated with .expandCollapsedMenu is this

.expandCollapsedMenu {
  -webkit-animation: expandCollapsedMenu 0.5s 1 forwards;
  -moz-animation: expandCollapsedMenu 0.5s 1 forwards;
  animation: expandCollapsedMenu 0.5s 1 forwards;
}

Comment: I don't understand why you think your code would apply the CSS if you don't add the class? I must be misunderstanding your question or your code

Answer (score 0):

The below scenario explains how the `ng-class` is working. The class should be first and you can have an optional condition following that.

```js
var app =angular.module("myapp", [])
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
$scope.isClass = false;
$scope.hide = function(){
$scope.isClass=!$scope.isClass;
}
})
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<button ng-click="hide()">Toggle</button>
<div style="background-color:red;width:100px;height:100px" ng-class="{hidden:isClass}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-class is used as

`ng-class="{'classname' : 'angular expression'}"`

e.g.

`ng-class="{'collapsedMenuAvailable' : true }"`

and your function call `vm.showVerticalBanner` needs parenthesis.

Use your controller to change the class names, which will be applied based on the expression. On ng-click call `vm.toggleClasses` function.

i.e if you want to apply `collapsedMenuAvailable` class then do something as

```
ng-class="{'collapsedMenuAvailable' : $scope.shouldApplyCollapsedMenuAvailable, 
'collapseCollapsedMenu' : $scope.shouldApplycollapseCollapsedMenu}"
```

and in controller:

```
vm.toggleClasses = function () {
$scope.shouldApplycollapseCollapsedMenu = !$scope.shouldApplycollapseCollapsedMenu;
$scope.shouldApplyCollapsedMenuAvailable = !$scope.shouldApplyCollapsedMenuAvailable;

}
```